# Link Tag is not working: Unclickable link

Tags: asp.net-core

I have this link below:

```
<a asp-page="./CreateNew">CreateNewLink</a>
```

Why is **CreateNewLink** not clickable after running the code?

Comment: Does `asp-page="CreateNew"` work? And what does your rendered output look like?

Comment: It is a simple text: CreateNewLink

Answer (score 1, accepted):

H
Make Sure That you declare usage of taghelpers in `_ViewImports.cshtml`

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

And then make sure you have the address  of page right because the `asp-page` will not render a `href` for a tag if the address is not valid

if this doesn't help, take a look at [MS DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/built-in/anchor-tag-helper?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 0):

When I try to use your code it breaks my application, changing to:

```
<a asp-page="/CreateNew">CreateNewLink</a>
```

Works and shows a clickable link:
[image]